# Regex for 2 items but with one exclusion

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am building a RegEx that needs to find lines that have either:

```
DateTime.Now
or 
Date.Now
```

But cannot have the literal "`SystemDateTime`" on the same line.

I started with this `(DateTime\.Now|Date\.Now)` but now I am stuck with where to put the "`SystemDateTime`"

Answer (score 0):

Use this. Assuming you are not using `/s` modifier(or `DOTALL`) which takes newline characters under the dot(`.`)

```
(?!.*SystemDateTime)(DateTime\.Now|Date\.Now)
```

`(?!.*SystemDateTime)` means there is no `SystemDateTime` in front.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) like this:

```
(?!.*SystemDateTime)\bDate(?:Time)?\.Now\b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/(?!.*SystemDateTime)Date(?:Time)?\.Now/
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hB1gZ8)

**EXPLANATION:**

```
Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead) «(?!.*SystemDateTime)»
   Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
   Match the characters “SystemDateTime” literally «SystemDateTime»
Match the characters “Date” literally «Date»
Match the regular expression below «(?:Time)?»
   Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
   Match the characters “Time” literally «Time»
Match the character “.” literally «\.»
Match the characters “Now” literally «Now»
```